# What does "burst fire count" mean?

Tags: borderlands

Some of the guns in Borderlands have a burst fire count. What does that mean? For example, [Sledge's Shotgun](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Weapon_Effects#Shotguns):

> *The Legend Lives, [Sledge's Shotgun](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sledge%27s_Shotgun_%28Borderlands%29): Knocks back target several feet and **10000% burst fire count***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refers to how many rounds it fires, and possibly also how quickly it fires them. A quick search turned up this post: [+burst fire count](http://web.archive.org/web/20120508024854/http://borderlandsguide.com/forum/burst-fire-count).

> Basically, Burst fire is how many shots it fires off in the span of a normal shot. So a gun that shoots 1 round a second would be 1.0 ROF, but if it was burst +100% it would shoot 2 every second. A burst fire pistol with a +500% will shoot 6 rounds in the time it would normally shoot 1. So... 1 trigger squeeze = 6 bullets. The 10,000% on Sledge's shotgun just makes the rounds almost instintanious, since it's only a 2 round gun. Basically double barrel.